# Reverse iteration in a jQuery Object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object, iteration

```
 var   test_data =  {'hr' : [1, 'Hour'], 'min' : [60, 'Minute'], 's' : [3600, 'Second']}
```

Now while I iterate, I want to get 's' first-

```
$.each(test_data, function(i, j) {
         // I need to get 's' first
});
```

I have tried `test_data.revers()` which does not work. Any solution?

Comment: That's not a jQuery object. Does the object always have those three keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a defined order, you could sort the keys of the object and iterate them in descending order of the first value of the array.

```js
var data = { hr: [1, 'Hour'], min: [60, 'Minute'], s: [3600, 'Second'] };

for (const key of Object.keys(data).sort((a, b) => data[b][0] - data[a][0])) {
    console.log(key, ...data[key]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [`.reverse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) as follows:

```js
var test_data = {
  'hr' : [1, 'Hour'], 
  'min' : [60, 'Minute'], 
  's' : [3600, 'Second']
};

$.each(Object.keys(test_data).reverse(), function(i, key) {
  console.log(key, test_data[key]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```